# Google Map Working Fine in .html page but not in ASP.NET page

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

I've developed a html page where two input textbox take two address as start and end location. A button(Submit) is used to show that location's path in google map (used google map api) and the right side of the page the direction description and total distance will be shown. Well it is working fine in .html(extension ) page but in my asp.net page (.aspx) extension it is not working. My tried code is given below. where is the problem ? Help me . Any suggestion Please to achieving  the requirement.
I've tried different type script link with  what I've given from google in my MY_API_KEY. 
    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap&sensor=false
    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&sensor=false

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&sensor=false&callback=initMap
```

But it didn't work in ASP.NET ..................

[image]
[image]
java script console output:
Browsers console output:
[image]
[image]

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GoogleMapLocation.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.GoogleMapLocation" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps API (v3): directions with custom icons</title>
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>      
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
// this variable will collect the html which will eventually be placed in the side_bar 
var side_bar_html = "";
var gmarkers = [];
var map = null;
var startLocation = null;
var endLocation = null;
var directionsService = null;
var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
path: [],
strokeColor: '#FF0000',
strokeWeight: 3
});

function initialize() {

side_bar_html = "";

gmarkers = [];
map = null;
startLocation = null;
endLocation = null;
directionsService = null;
polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
path: [],
strokeColor: '#FF0000',
strokeWeight: 3
});
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(23.777176, 90.399452);
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
center: center,
zoom: 13,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () {
infowindow.close();
});
directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
var request = {
origin: start,
destination: end,
travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
};

directionsService.route(request, RenderCustomDirections);
}

function RenderCustomDirections(response, status) {
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    var route = response.routes[0];
    var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");
var detailsPanel = document.getElementById("direction_details");
    startLocation = new Object();
    endLocation = new Object();

    summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";
    detailsPanel.innerHTML = '<ul>';

    // For each route, display summary information.
    for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
var routeSegment = i + 1;
summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<b>Route Segment: " + routeSegment + "</b><br />";
    summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
    summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + "<br />";
summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + "<br /><br />";
}
var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
if (i == 0) {
startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
startLocation.marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location, "start", legs[i].start_address, "green");
}
endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
var steps = legs[i].steps;
for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
detailsPanel.innerHTML += "<li>" + steps[j].instructions;
var dist_dur = "";
if (steps[j].distance && steps[j].distance.text) dist_dur += "&nbsp;" + steps[j].distance.text;
if (steps[j].duration && steps[j].duration.text) dist_dur += "&nbsp;" + steps[j].duration.text;
if (dist_dur != "") {
detailsPanel.innerHTML += "(" + dist_dur + ")<br /></li>";
} else {
detailsPanel.innerHTML += "</li>";

}
for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
}
}
}
detailsPanel.innerHTML += "</ul>"
polyline.setMap(map);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
endLocation.marker = createMarker(endLocation.latlng, "end", endLocation.address, "red");
// == create the initial sidebar ==
makeSidebar();
}
else alert(status);
}
var icons = new Array();
icons["red"] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("mapIcons/marker_red.png",
    // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
    new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
    // The origin for this image is 0,0.
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
    new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
function getMarkerImage(iconColor) {
if ((typeof (iconColor) == "undefined") || (iconColor == null)) {
iconColor = "red";
}
if (!icons[iconColor]) {
icons[iconColor] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("mapIcons/marker_" + iconColor + ".png",
    // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
    new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
    // The origin for this image is 0,0.
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    // The anchor for this image is at 6,20.
    new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
}
return icons[iconColor];
}
var iconImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('mapIcons/marker_red.png',
    // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
    new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
    // The origin for this image is 0,0.
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
    new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
var iconShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png',
    // The shadow image is larger in the horizontal dimension
    // while the position and offset are the same as for the main image.
    new google.maps.Size(37, 34),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
var iconShape = {
coord: [9, 0, 6, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 0, 8, 0, 12, 1, 14, 2, 16, 5, 19, 7, 23, 8, 26, 9, 30, 9, 34, 11, 34, 11, 30, 12, 26, 13, 24, 14, 21, 16, 18, 18, 16, 20, 12, 20, 8, 18, 4, 16, 2, 15, 1, 13, 0],
type: 'poly'
};
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
    {
    size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
    });
function createMarker(latlng, label, html, color) {
// alert("createMarker("+latlng+","+label+","+html+","+color+")");
var contentString = '<b>' + label + '</b><br>' + html;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: latlng,
draggable: true,
map: map,
shadow: iconShadow,
icon: getMarkerImage(color),
shape: iconShape,
title: label,
zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
});
marker.myname = label;
gmarkers.push(marker);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
infowindow.setContent(contentString);
infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {
// alert("drag ended! start:"+startLocation.marker.getPosition()+" end:"+endLocation.marker.getPosition());
var request = {
origin: startLocation.marker.getPosition(),
destination: endLocation.marker.getPosition(),
travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
};
startLocation.marker.setMap(null);
endLocation.marker.setMap(null);
gmarkers = [];
polyline.setMap(null);
polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
path: [],
strokeColor: '#FF0000',
strokeWeight: 3
});
directionsService.route(request, RenderCustomDirections);
});
return marker;
}
function myclick(i) {
google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}
// == rebuilds the sidebar to match the markers currently displayed ==
function makeSidebar() {
var html = "";
for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + gmarkers[i].myname + '<\/a><br>';
}
document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = html;
}
//]]>
</script>       
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
#map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
</head>
<body >
<div id="tools">
start:
<input type="text" name="start" id="start" value="Luxmibazar,Dhaka,Bangladesh"/>
end:
<input type="text" name="end" id="end" value="Jahangirnagar University,Savar,Bangladesh"/>
<input type="submit" onclick="initialize();"/>
</div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="float:left;width:70%;height:100%;"></div>
<div id="control_panel" style="float:right;width:30%;text-align:left;padding-top:20px">
<table border="1"><tr><td>
<div id="directions_panel" style="margin:20px;background-color:#FFEE77;"></div>
</td></tr><tr><td>
<div id="direction_details" style="margin:20px;"></div>
</td></tr><tr><td>
<div id="side_bar" style="margin:20px;"></div>
</td></tr></table>
</div>
<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
_uacct = "UA-162157-1";
urchinTracker();
</script>       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As the arror says, show us the Javascript console's output.

Comment: I've add the Javascript console's output @rnli. thanks

Comment: @Mithun i want your browser console

Comment: I've add the Browser  console's output for @ Webruster. thanks.

Comment: @Webruster , You have pointed me the right direction to solve the problem by telling me to look at the browser console's output. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the javascript console prints out in the first lines - you are missing the API key parameter.

[Missing key map error](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error)

[No API keys error](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys)

See the two sites for more information and follow the introductions for [getting and using an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key). You have to add the key parameter with `&key=YOUR_KEY` to this line `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">`.

Afterwards you will find your API key [here](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) at the credentials page. There you can check and change the allowed HTTP referrers.

Please read the error message correctly next time. All the information (even the links) are given there.

*Moreover the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 no longer requires the sensor parameter.*

Comment: I've Tried but no result. I've given the script in my question blog @mxlse. thanks

Comment: So you got a key at https://console.developers.google.com and added the right key? Then the error message should be different. You can also check the allowed HTTP referrers for your API key at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

Comment: Yes. I got the key and used it . it gives me another RefererNotAllowedMapError  error. 
Now I've solved this. Thanks to you.

Comment: Very good! I added it to the answer. So accepting it would be appreciated.